# Spring xml context file not found

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to learn Spring Framework following this tutorial:

```
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.htm
```

I have create a new Maven project with:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

Is not a Web application. I want to create a simple java application and my main method is:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
obj.getMessage();
```

If i'm not wrong ClassPathXmlApplicationContext constructor looks for the file on the src/main/resources folder. But when i execute the application i got the exception "File not found beans.xml". I tried with the full route to the beans.xml file src/main/resources/beans.xml and tons of routes.

When i use this code to check the existence of my file it says that exists.

```
File f = new File("src/main/resources/beans.xml");
System.out.println("Exist test: " + f.exists());
```

I don't get it. Any help please?

Another thing that i wanted to ask is if i need to use xml to get Dependency Injection. Can i work with spring framework without using XML definitions?

I have seen Annotations like @Autowired and more but i can't get it working also. I wonder if i need to use a combination of xml+annotations.

Comment: Right click `src/main/resources` and select Build > Add to Build Path

Comment: I was using Netbeans but i click on properties on my project and then on Spring Framework on "Add Files" and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the file in the root directory of your classpath (and that is what you do) use

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/beans.xml");
```

to reference it ("/" at the beginning).

You don't need XML configuration. Have a look at the [Spring Framwork Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/). Chapter [5.9 Annotation-based container configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-annotation-config) and [5.12 Java-based container configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java) explain Java Configuration in Detail.

Answer (score 0):

ClassPathXmlApplicationContext doesn't look for the file in the /src/main/resources. It tries to find it in the classpath (the "root" of your jar file).

But everything you put in the src/main/resources will be put in the "root" (in the classpath so) by maven when you build your application.